# Laravel Join Tables with intermediate relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 Tables.`1) Recent Views` `2) posts` and `3) users`. i need to join these three tables with intermediate relation.

```
recent table
------------
id
post_id
user_id
date
```

```
posts table
-----------
id
user_id
post_title
description
date
```

```
users table
-----------
id
username
image
email
date
```

now what is need to get is all data from `recent table` where `user_id = logged_users_id` -> join `posts table` with `recent.post_id = posts.id` -> join 'users table' with `posts.user_id = users.id`. how can i do this with laravel eloquent? can someone help me with this?

Code i have used is:

```
$contents = RecentView::where('user_id', $loggedUser)
                ->with('posts')
                ->with('user')
                ->paginate(12)
                ->toArray();
```

but it joins user table with recent.user_id = users.id

Comment: Does the code you wrote work now? Or are you looking for a better solution?

Comment: No. the result i get is wrong. from user table what is get is logged users details for every post and not post owner details

Comment: also a better solution suggestion will be greatfull if am doing anything wrong as am a newbiw with laravel

Comment: Test the sample I sent

Comment: tried. but getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$contents = RecentView::where('recent_views.user_id', $loggedUser)
->leftJoin('feed_posts','recent_views.post_id','=','feed_posts.id')
->leftJoin('users','feed_posts.user_id','=','users.id')
->paginate(12)->toArray();
```

**Just check the table name and the rest**

Comment: ```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `recent_views` inner join `feed_posts` on `recent_views`.`post_id` = `feed_posts`.`id` inner join `users` on `feed_posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `user_id` = 235)
```

Comment: Is your table name feed_posts?

Comment: You send the exact name of the tables and columns.

Comment: yes. tables are 'recent_views', 'feed_posts' and 'users'

Comment: `recent_views`
`-----------------`
`id`
`user_id`
`post_id`
`-----------------`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224684/discussion-between-akbar-rahmanii-and-compulsive-coder).

Comment: that worked!!!

can u please edit `->leftJoin('users','posts.user_id','=','users.id')` to `->leftJoin('users','feed_posts.user_id','=','users.id')` so that i can mark this as accepted answer?